# Why does Vim in Ubuntu 20.04 require Python 3?

Tags: apt, python, python3, vim

I'm using Docker, and my *dockerfile* is:

```
######################################################
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /opt/test

# Apt installs
RUN apt update

######################################################
```

If I build and run the container, and then run the following, it asks to install python3-minimal, and Python dependencies:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu-test
root@3a13a90d3e86:/opt/test# apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf file libasound2 libasound2-data libcanberra0 libexpat1 libgpm2 libltdl7 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpdec2 libogg0 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0
  libssl1.1 libtdb1 libvorbis0a libvorbisfile3 mime-support readline-common sound-theme-freedesktop vim-common vim-runtime xxd xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  libasound2-plugins alsa-utils libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse gpm readline-doc ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf file libasound2 libasound2-data libcanberra0 libexpat1 libgpm2 libltdl7 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpdec2 libogg0 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0
  libssl1.1 libtdb1 libvorbis0a libvorbisfile3 mime-support readline-common sound-theme-freedesktop vim vim-common vim-runtime xxd xz-utils
0 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

These files are in the list:
`libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib`

Why does Vim require Python?

(This is messing up my Docker image, because I actually need Vim, but I also need 32-bit Python. So I need python3:i386, but Vim is messing it up by installing 64-bit Python too).

Comment: The developer listed it as required - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim

Comment: @guiverc yes well obviously, but *why*?

Comment: `vim` allows more features (including extensions) that the developer has added using `python` which is a common language today.  The original `vi` was written in days where the cost of interpreted languages was too high so only low-level compiled languages made sense (1970s)

Comment: You may not need vim in the docker image—vim can edit over the network, so you could use that to edit files on the container via your system’s vim.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I figured out if I install vim:i386 it'll install the required 32-bit libraries instead and I can have both.

Answer (score 25):

I would guess that the package `vim` is [compiled with support](https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim/-/blob/debian/sid/debian/rules#L109) for python.  You might have better luck installing the package `vim-tiny`.

Answer (score 16):

This is not new in 20.04. The same is true in [18.04 (with Python 3.6 instead, of course)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/vim). And in [16.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/vim/2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.5), once a **regression** was fixed ([LP #1574897](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1574897)). Even back in 12.04, [the `vim` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/vim) depended on Python (2.7 at the time). This supports Python scripting inside Vim.

Answer (score 6):

The developer listed it as required - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim

Your option could also be to use `vi` instead

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvi

which shows no python3 requirement.